# Модуль angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Создаю модуль AngularJS в файле app.js

```
var todoApp = angular.module("todoApp", []);
```

Ошибка:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Comment: ваш app.js грузится до angular

Comment: весь код бросай. так не поймешь что у тебя

Comment: @zamutil ну зачем там весь код, код скорее всего с туториала todoMVC :)  просто надо проверить порядок подключения js в html

Comment: @eicto так а как проверить порядок подключения? я свою Вангу оставил дома, к сожалению)

Comment: ну уж точно не по app.js :)

Answer (score 3):

Как уже отметили в комментариях, похоже на то, что файл app.js подключен раньше чем angular.js.
В index.html должно подключение скриптов выглядеть примерно так:

```
<!-- сначала angular.js -->
<script src="path/to/angular.js">
<!-- и только после него app.js -->
<script src="path/to/app.js">
```

Comment: либо была ошибка загрузки ангуляра

Comment: Спасибо помогло, как-то совсем невнимательно подключил скрипты и соответственно